# insufficient privileges using dbms_sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a PLSQL code using dbms_sql package. For example it starts with sequence creation.

```
request:= 'CREATE SEQUENCE ' || utilisateur || '.' || 'seq_fusion_table
                MINVALUE 1
                START WITH 1
                INCREMENT BY 1';
dbms_sql.parse(curseur_ref, request, dbms_sql.native);
response := dbms_sql.execute(curseur_ref);
```

I have an error :

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

I thought the user could not use dbms_sql so I sent this request :

```
GRANT execute on DBMS_SQL to user;
commit;
```

And just to be sure I sent the creation request without using dbms_sql and indeed the user has the right to create sequences.

What should I do to get rid of this insufficient privileges error ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Privileges granted through a *role* are not active inside PL/SQL. You need to grant the privilege to create sequences *directly* to the user:

```
grant create sequence to the_user;
```

Then it should also work from within PL/SQL.